# tool to publish mail (from Exchange server) on the internal web site

Tags: web-server, exchange, email-server

When we work on specific defects or features, many important discussions and decisions comes in via mail.   I would like to forward all mails to an email id and that publishes e-mails on a web. Is there a solution I can deploy an intranet server?

Our mail server is Microsoft Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sharepoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287981(office.12).aspx) (shudder) does this out of the box - you can give a Document Library an email address, and any messages sent to that address will get saved in the Document Library.